# Email blacklisted?

Tags: email, email-filter

I have an email account on a domain I own i.e. name@domain.co.uk.  I do not use this email account a lot.  However, I have noticed that when I send an email from this email account to my hotmail account, then the email always appears in the Junk Mail folder of my Hotmaol account.

I have spoken to the host of the domain and they say that I am on a shared server where other users could be spamming.  They have also asked me to speak to my ISP.

Can I see if my email address it somehow blacklisted by Hotmail?

Comment: Feel free to contact Microsoft about this problem.  If it is blacklisted then Microsoft is in the best position to confirm.

Comment: Individual Email addresses cannot be blacklisted, only entire domains. Further, *most* email systems which act upon a blacklisting will entirely block the message, not simply treat it as junk (I stress *most*).

Comment: [mxtoolbox.com](http://mxtoolbox.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get some more information from here:
https://www.ultratools.com/tools/spamDBLookupResult

I had this problem with shared hosting in the past. I think the responsible one is the owner of the IP, so I don't see how your IP (your home IP) has anything to do with that.